# How to call faker class via helper function as property rather then array

Tags: php, laravel, helper

I am trying to create a helper function for the faker package to be able to easily create fake data.

Currently I have a function which works as an array function.
eg.
`faker('sentence')`

But I want it to work by calling properties in the same way it is used in the laravel factory classes, but cant seem to get it to work.

eg.
`faker()->sentence`

Currently I have

```php
use Faker\Factory;

if (!function_exists('faker')) {
    /**
     * Get faker data
     *
     * @return Faker\Factory;;
     */

    function faker($property)
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();
        return $property ? $faker->{$property} : $faker;
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a facade like Laravel does for the `App` and `View` classes?

Comment: thats correct, so i can call faker()->name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it Looks like the issue I had was to do with the way the helper was being loaded. The faker function already can be called both ways.

faker('name')

faker()->name

```php
use Faker\Factory;

if (!function_exists('faker')) {
    /**
     * Get faker data
     *
     * @return Faker\Factory;;
     */

    function faker($property)
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();
        return $property ? $faker->{$property} : $faker;
    }


}
```

Comment: you probably want to adjust the function signature `faker($property = null)`